# when running a validating nodes, firewall setting is essential?

Tags: error, api, nodes, networking, cli

when running a nodes, firewall is essential?

i used this command `sudo ufw allow 3033/tpc` but it`s result is "ERROR: Bad port"

what`s the problem? can i just done "sudo ufw enable" without allow 3033/tpc ?

i can see my node still working in the telemetry while i just done "sudo ufw enable" only without allow 3033/tpc.

Comment: can you share the command which you are using for running your validator node?

Comment: It would be better to understand, if you can also tell us what command you are using?

Comment: "ExecStart=polkadot --validator --name 'AAA' --pruning=1000"
 in the systemctl, is it related??